# What is the difference between the owning entity and non-owning entity in a ManyToMany relationship (@JoinTable)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, many-to-many, join, jpa-2.1

I have two entities: Apikey and Api. These are joined using a join table:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTIVE_APIS(
API_ID      INTEGER NOT NULL,
API_KEY_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_API_ID_API_KEY_ID PRIMARY KEY (API_ID, API_KEY_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_API_ID        FOREIGN KEY (API_ID)        REFERENCES  APIS (API_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_API_KEY_ID    FOREIGN KEY (API_KEY_ID)    REFERENCES  API_KEYS (API_KEY_ID)
);
```

What is the behavioral difference between this (inside Apikey.class):

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="ACTIVE_APIS",
    joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="API_KEY_ID", referencedColumnName="API_KEY_ID")
        }, 
        inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="API_ID", referencedColumnName="API_ID")
        }
    )
private List<Api> activeapis;
```

And this (inside Api.class):

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="ACTIVE_APIS",
    joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="API_ID", referencedColumnName="API_ID")
        }, 
        inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="API_KEY_ID", referencedColumnName="API_KEY_ID")
        }
    )
private List<Apikey> apikeys
```

I suspect it has something to do with deletions but the doc says nothing: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html#joinColumns().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no behavioral difference.

Since there are no join columns in either of the entity tables, there is no way to determine an owning/inverse side of the relationship. Rather each side can be seen as both owning and inverse side at the same time.

Where you put the annotation is a matter of choice, just dont put them on both sides - same is valid for the `mappedBy` attribute in case you are relying on the default naming convention.